# C++ filtering debug events

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, events

Is there a built-in way in C++/Windows to filter events that `WaitForDebugEvent` captures?  that `WaitForDebugEvent` will just ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you can filter any debug event. The application calling WaitForDebugEvent will get all the events. You can, however ignore any particular event after receiving it in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call WaitForDebugEvent(), you do so in a loop.  If you're not interested in the notification then simply ignore it.  Just omit the case in your switch statement on DEBUG_EVENT.dwDebugEventCode.  That's filtering it.